# Problems with Netflix-App after upgrading to 13.04

Tags: netflix

I recently upgrade  my desktop to 13.04 Xunbuntu with no errors or issues at all. However now I am getting a need to upgrade silverlight screen in netflix using the netflix app.

I realized this is a 3rd party application running a wine patch of Firefox/Silverlight and  the Ubuntu Team is not responsible for providing a solution, but at least I want to put it out there for other people who are considering upgrading.

I did try to upgrade the netflix application and, it did call for an update but it did not work. I still run Xubuntu 12.10 in my laptop and it is running like a champ! with no issues with Netflix App.

I hate going back to the days of dual reboot in order to watch Netflix but aside from this issue 13.04 runs great! Please if someone else have run to an issue similar to mines. I would love hear how you got around it.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to solve this issues, by using the information on this [website](http://www.iheartubuntu.com/2012/11/ppa-for-netflix-desktop-app.html).

It worked for me! But please be aware I am a newbie at Ubuntu so do it at your own risk!

1. Remove recursively directory and it's content from `~/.wine-browser`:

   ```
   rm -Rf ~/.wine-browser
   ```
2. Uninstall and purge `netflix-desktop`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge netflix-desktop
   ```
3. I'm assuming you've added the PPA repository, if not:

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ehoover/compholio
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Install `netflix-desktop`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install netflix-desktop
   ```

When you run `netflix-desktop` application. it will ask to install moonlight and wine gecko say 'yes' to both and **Presto!** Netflix is back! No more update requirements.

It also seems to be working after I log out and come back or reboot. I am not a programmer nor an experience Linux user but I am guessing it has to do with patching Netflix App, Monolight and Gecko Wine installer.